# How to handle TFS password on multiple Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins, credentials

I have set up a few Jenkins jobs which are using TFS. For each one I had to manually input TFS username and password inside the TFS plugin. 
Is there a way to change password in all jobs using some king of global setting? Or do I have to manually change password on all jobs when I change my password.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get latest TFS (5.0.0) and Credentials (2.1.4) plugins.

Add domain and credentials usable to connect to your TFS server via Jenkins > Configure Credentials.

Now select just added domain, click "Configure", and add your TFS server hostname (or proper wildcard) under Hostname > Include, so jenkins will know where provided credentials can be used.

Now, you can just leave user/password fields empty in job's TFS SCM configuration.

Instructions are mostly taken from [TFS plugin GitHub page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#global-configuration)

Even though TFS Plugin bug [Allow use of credentials from Credentials Plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13663) isn't resolved, all is working fine.

Comment: Thanks... Btw I needed to add TFS credentials in Configure System > TFS/Team Services and things started working afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The TFS Plugin for Jenkins does not read the global credentials. You need to enter the username and password for each job manually.

Comment: Thanks so it cannot be done. Its a pain but i guess there is no way. Again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the Jenkins admin you can add "global" credentials. For this, as a Jenkins admin, go in :

**Manage Jenkins** > **Manage Credentials** > **Add Credentials** > **Username with password** and save it.

These credentials will be available in all the jobs configuration of this Jenkins instance.

If you don't the the **Manage Credentials** item, you'll maybe need to install the [Jenkins Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)

Comment: I have the credential plugin installed. I have also entered my username password there. But this doesnt get available in my job. Is there anyother plugin i need to make it available in Tfs or am i missing aome step?