# How to login Jenkins using VS TFS credentials

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

Currently, All our team members are using same username & password to login Jenkins. Is there a way, which allows Jenkins login using VS TFS login credentials for each members separately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, Our team has more than 100 people, so manually creating users with a password for all is not feasible.

Comment: Hi @Priya22, I have updated the answer, check the update1, you could also refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674626/how-to-handle-tfs-password-on-multiple-jenkins-jobs) for more details. You could also try it with AD plugin.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Login Jenkins as admin->Jenkins->Manage Jenkins-> Configure Global Security->enable the feature **Logged-in users can do anything**

[image]

Manage Jenkins->Manage User->Create User->enter username and password with TFS credentials->click the button **Create User**

Then you could login Jenkins with TFS credentials.

[image]

**Update1**

Add domain and credentials usable to connect to your TFS server via Jenkins > Configure Credentials.

Now select just added domain, click "Configure", and add your TFS server hostname (or proper wildcard) under Hostname > Include, so jenkins will know where provided credentials can be used.

Now, you can just leave user/password fields empty in job's TFS SCM configuration.

Instructions are mostly taken from [TFS plugin GitHub page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#global-configuration)

Comment: I would have assumed that users authenticate to TFS using AD, so install the AD plugin, configure and off you go. Is that not what OP meant by "TFS login credentials"?